# Overwritten __repr__ after instance creation

Tags: python

I am playing a little bit around with Python metaprogramming.

```
class FormMetaClass(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, methods):
        # Attach attribute names to the descriptors
        for key, value in methods.items():
            if isinstance(value, FieldDescriptor):
                value.name = key
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, methods)


class Form(metaclass=FormMetaClass):

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, incoming):
        instance = cls()
        data = json.loads(incoming)
        for k, v in data.items():
            if (not hasattr(instance, k)):
                raise KeyError("Atrribute not found")
            instance.__setattr__(k, v)
        return cls

class MyForm(Form):

    first_name = String()
    last_name = String()
    age = Integer()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)


def main():
    data = json.dumps({'first_name': 'Thomas',
                       'last_name': 'Junk'})
    form = MyForm.from_json(data)
    print(form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

class FieldDescriptor:

    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        self.name = name
        for key, value in opts.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value


class Typechecked(FieldDescriptor):
    expected_type = type(None)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        super().__set__(instance, value)


class Integer(Typechecked):
    expected_type = int


class String(Typechecked):
    expected_type = str
```

I have a `Form` which has a metaclass `FormMetaClass`.
To have an alternative constructor I am using a `@classmethod`.
I create an `instance`, which seem to work so far.

What doesn't work is calling the `__repr__` (or `__str__` interchangeably).
When I create an instance via `MyForm()` everything is fine.
When I create an instance via the `@classmethod`, some "default" implementation is taken.

I expected `Thomas Junk`, but I get `<class '__main__.MyForm'>`

Could you give me a hint, what I am overlooking?

Comment: Presumably the `field.String()` and `field.Integer()` objects are `FieldDescriptor` instances? I'm trying to see if I can reproduce your issue, but this is not a [mcve] with those objects missing.

Comment: Added the Descriptors.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce it already, without the descriptors.

Comment: In future do try to reduce your example to the smallest example; your problem didn't actually have anything to do with metaclasses or descriptors, you could have removed those and still observed the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes. Stupid me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the class, not the newly created instance:

```
return cls
```

So you return `MyForm`, not the new instance `MyForm()` you just set all the attributes on. And you indeed see the `repr()` output for the class:

```
>>> form is MyForm
True
>>> print(MyForm)
<class '__main__.MyForm'>
```

The fix is simple, return `instance` instead:

```
return instance
```

or, as a full method:

```
@classmethod
def from_json(cls, incoming):
    instance = cls()
    data = json.loads(incoming)
    for k, v in data.items():
        if (not hasattr(instance, k)):
            raise KeyError("Atrribute not found")
        instance.__setattr__(k, v)
    return instance
```

at which point the method returns an instance and everything works:

```
>>> isinstance(form, MyForm)
True
>>> print(form)
Thomas Junk
```